# Recursive instead of for Loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

The datas :

```
missionIds : ['ID1', 'ID2'...] is an Array of String
this.tabDataManager : [{JOBOPENINGID: "ID1"}, {JOBOPENINGID: "ID2"}...] is an Array of Objects
```

The classic Loop is working and i have the result expected :

```
for (var i=0; i < this.missionIds.length; i++ ){
      for(var j=0; j< this.tabDataManager.length; j++){
        if(this.missionIds[i] === this.tabDataManager[j].JOBOPENINGID){
          console.log('true');
        }//END if
      }//END for
    }//END for
```

The recursive version is not working and i have an empty array as result :

```
this.tabDataManager = this.tabDataManager.filter(ref => ref.JOBOPENINGID === this.missionIds.map(def => def))
```

D u have an idea why ?

Comment: please add the wanted result. do you want a new data structure?

Comment: A recursive function should call itself. Yours is not doing that and is therefor not recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with the wanted value.

```
this.tabDataManager = this.tabDataManager.filter(ref => 
    this.missionIds.includes(ref.JOBOPENINGID);
```

Comment: Thanks its working, didn't now .includes function ! Recursive is a 
long learning curve :)

Comment: @Jeremie-Segu: there is nothing about this solution or either version in your question that is recursive.  This is a step along the way from an imperative coding style to a declarative one, and possibly movement toward a more functional style.  But there is nothing of recursion here.